# How to disable automatically build for only one project?

Tags: eclipse, build

I have one huge project that I use only for source viewing. But the building of that project required to much time. However, I want to disable the automatically build only for this project. Is it possible?

thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve here, but you can also disable individual builders for a project via Project Properties.

Comment: More details? I cannot find it per project. I am using Mars (4.5).

Comment: Right click the project → `Properties` → `Builders` → uncheck `Java Builder` (or whatever other builder you want to disable)

Answer (score 1):

Create two working sets - one with and one without the big project. Then switch between the two working sets as you need and build as you need, and try to experiment with this feature.

From the help docs:

> Working sets may also be a part of a manual build workflow. With
>   autobuild disabled the Project > Build Working Set menu becomes
>   enabled. From here you are able to selectively build working sets of
>   your choosing.

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution is launch another instance of Eclipse in a separate workspace and operate this project only, with auto-build turned off. Unless your RAM is heavily loaded, a separate Eclipse instance is better choice for such need.

Comment: I doesn't looks like a solution though: you have to switch between instances etc. - that all adds a huge overhead to the work process.

Comment: In this case, have to do some tweaking: uncheck the builders for the unwanted projects which stops them from auto-build, and add custom builder (ant, etc) which can be triggered by explicit manual build (ctrl-b), while leaving the one project auto-build.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is to use the Inclusion and Exclusion Patterns option in the Java Build Path. 
For example if you want to exclude one project of being automatically build: 
1- Go to its Properties->Java Build Path->Source. 
2- Expand the folder in the "Source folders on the build path:" area 
3- Select Exclude->Edit 
4- In the exclusion patterns add ** 
Note: for more information on this patterns: [Include and Exclusion Patterns](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/concepts/concept-inclusion-exclusion-patterns.htm&cp=1_2_1_0_0)

Comment: I tried this in my ADT setup where I was referencing several Android Library projects, and it caused errors that were not resolved until re-introducing some projects.  I'm guessing this solution works in certain cases .. but for the setup I have, unfortunately not.  I would probably try it again in a non-ADT env.